# Jquery scrollTop always scrolling to top of page, NOT top of element found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cart, when the "X" for any item in the cart is clicked, I want the page to scroll such that the immediately previous item in the cart is at the top of the page.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qb3a6j31/9/

If for example you scroll to the very bottom, and click the "X" on Item #4, I want the page to scroll such that Item #3 is at the very top (or as far to the top as possible, given how much content there is below). However, the behavior that is happening now is that clicking on any "X" always scrolls to the top of the page, not the top of the found element.

I have a `console.log` as well that shows the correct element is being found to scroll to. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your scrollTop animation to this:

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: element_to_scroll_to.position().top }, 1);
```

Comment: when you call [scrolltop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) on an element, it gives the amount of scroll within the element, not its location on the page. (you can have a scroll bar INSIDE of an html element, by setting the `overflow:scroll` css property. if you had a `<div>` with `overflow:scroll`, `scrollTop()` would give you the amount of internal scroll in that tag.) Hope this makes sense...it sounds more complicated than it is

Comment: oh i see, in other words, my approach would have worked if it were like this `parent_of_element_to_scroll_to.scrollTop( some_parameter_of_pixels_to_get_to_element_to_scroll_to)` right?

Comment: No. You wanted to scroll the entire page, so you do scrollTop on the html/body tag. You know how the textbox where you type in questions/answers/comments on stackoverflow will sometimes have a scroll bar on it, if the text is too long for the size of the text box? You call scrollTop on an element to scroll the ELEMENT's  scroll bar, not the whole page's scroll bar.

Comment: Can I confirm that this should look like:  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: .foo.position().top }, 1); This raises a syntax error for me.

Comment: @Dan382 in your sample you have `.foo.position().top` ... assuming it's not a typo, my guess is that first dot is causing your syntax error. did you perhaps mean to type `scrollTop: foo.position().top`? Also in case that's just a typo, in your example is `foo` a jQuery instance? Because `position()` is a jQuery function.